# Swap/change text based on a character in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

So I have let's say thousands of rows like this (not in any pattern):

```
example1:example2
example3:
example4:
example5:example6
example7:
```

etc...

and my goal is to on the lines that have something after the colon for it to swap with the the text behind it as the following

```
example1:example2
```

to

```
example2:example1
```

and on the lines that don't have anything after the colon, to delete those lines, and I don't know how to go about it in sublime text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First perform a replace operation (Find -> Replace or CTRL + H)

Enable regex (there is a button with `.*`) in it and replace with the following settings

#### Swap colon-seperated items

Find `(.*):(.+)`

Replace: `$2:$1`

#### Remove items without content after colon

Find: `.*:$`

Replace: (nothing)

Comment: I said "example1" and "example2" as an example but the lines that I have is all random, so how would I do it then?

Comment: @Naji This should even if your lines are all random. It just swaps colon seperated items and remove lines without data after the colon